Remove geometry from half of the model with Geometry Nodes

This is my current geo node setup to get an outline around the model. How do I stop it from generating geometry on this flat side?
Maybe there is some sort of model coordinate gradient that can cut off the geometry Boolean style?

I think you're missing some vital information about Perspective Geometry that many of us notice in some illustrators who transition to 3D modeling for the first time. That "flat side" is not generated from some elaborate modeling. Instead, it becomes visible when your point of perspective is not aligned to the cut you made on the mesh.

It seems you are trying to mask or cover up the visible cross-section with geometry nodes. However, this will never truly cover up the flat side that you don't want to see. Are you actually looking for a node tree that will make the cut and remove half of your geometry from your point of perspective instead?

Yes I am aware how this effect works so I just need something to procedurally cut off some of the generated "solidify type" geometry that is the outline. Like something that just cuts it off after certain local y coordinate

This set up will do exactly as what you requested in your comment and your question.

I simply took the model’s origin as a vertex and projected it to the camera’s view. From there, I extruded it out into a line before extruding it into a plane to cut the model. What values did I use for extrusion? I simply chose some basic lengths that I knew would be more than enough to use.

I apologize if this wasn’t a very detailed explanation. Honestly, I didn’t spend much time cleaning this up. I just picked the first rough iteration I made that worked. A one trick pony like this, doesn’t really catch my attention. This question could have been resolved with far simpler methods. However, if you use it as an example to build other geometry node trees then, it can be pretty useful.

Blender 4.2.2

Just a warning. The Input Rotation for Cut from View does not work. Since I used a Set Position node for the Raycast node, I was able to extrude the line negatively to cut along the perspective path. However, I chose to rotate the cut around the z-axis instead of its direction to the object. This causes an angled cut when either the object or the camera is in a different position. As long as you keep the cut vertical with 0 degrees, it will work.

Consider a single-faced, flat plane. At what position in 3D space can we see either side of its only face? Almost anywhere in 3D space will allow us to see the surface of this plane when we’re looking at it.
The only way to not see the surface of this plane is if we orient our point of perspective or the position of the plane to its side view. To be more specific, we need to be looking at the plane at its edge where it directly overlaps with the edge across from it in our field of view. Only then are we unable to see the sides of the plane.
Now substitute that flat plane with the flat side of your model. If we don’t want to see the surface of the flat side, then we need to orient our point of perspective or the rotation of your model so that it is not visible to our field of view.

We’ll use a camera in place of our point of perspective or our field of view and we’ll choose to rotate the model so that the flat side is not visible.

If we orient the normal vector of your flat side to be perpendicular to our view, then we would have achieved our goal.

So, if your object is already cut, you can use a Track To constraint to orient your model. No matter where you're looking, your model will re-orient itself to always hide your flat side.

Blender 4.2.2

I wanted to include this exposition in my answer because it felt like your Perspective Geometry was lacking. However, it was too lengthy and somewhat off topic. Luckily, it turns out it can be considered its own answer.
